# Boost exception at runtime

Tags: c++, boost, runtime-error

Using this code:

```
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("c:\test");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
}
```

I'm getting an unhandled exception at runtime on executing the boost archive line:

```
boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::archive::archive_exception> >
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following line is in error:

```
 std::ofstream ofs("c:\test");
```

The compiler would've spit out a warning (at least) if your file was called `jest`; but `'\t'` -- being the escape for inserting a tab, your error goes by uncaught. In short, the file will not be created. You can test this with:

```
if (ofs.good()) { ... }
```

Now, since the file was not created, you don't have a valid iterator to pass on to `boost::archive::text_oarchive` which throws the exception.

Try this:

```
std::ofstream ofs("c:\\test");
//                  --^ (note the extra backslash)
if (ofs.good()) {
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

**PS:** A final nit I couldn't stop myself from making -- if you are going to use

```
using namespace std;
```

then

```
ofstream ofs("c:\\test");
```

is good enough. Of course, it is not an error to qualify `ofstream`, but it would not be the best coding style. But then, you know using `using namespace` is bad, don't you?

**PPS**:Thank you -- `sharptooth` for reminding me that `\t` gets you a tab!

Comment: \t is horizontal TAB, so the compiler is very very unlikely to feel the smell.

Comment: You could also just use c:/test - the forward slash works on both Windows and Unix systems as a path separator and doesn't need to be quoted.

Comment: Sure. Very few use it though on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, I very quickly figured it out after catching the exception (please excuse my asking this question, it had been a long day), but nonetheless there are some useful tips there, so thanks. I'm curious though, why is using namespace bad?

Comment: The `using namespace std' dumps all symbols in the std namespace to the global namespace causing pollution. Look up namespace pollution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the exception and then examine its exception_code to see what the root cause is.